# Multiple checkbox values in array gives strange characters in database

Tags: php, arrays, database, wordpress

I'm saving the values from a checkbox in an array to the database, but in the database the field contains strange characters like: s:44:"a:2:{i:0;s:8:"0-4 years";i:1;s:8:"10th group";}";

I only need the parts **0-4 years** and **10th group**. How can I prevent the characters get it the way I want?

This is part of the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="wmw_age[]" value="0-4 years">
<input type="checkbox" name="wmw_age[]" value="10th group">
```

This is the way I get it to the database after submit:

```
$data=serialize($_POST['wmw_age']);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'wmw_age', $data);
```

If both fields are checked, this is the result in the database:

```
s:44:"a:2:{i:0;s:8:"0-4 years";i:1;s:8:"10th group";}";
```

Is it possible to only get this in the database: 0-4 years, 10th group

I hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks.

Comment: Thats been `Serialize()`'d So you need to `unserialize()` it back to a PHP data structure

Comment: Or not even serialize it in the first place.

Comment: @FirstOne Yea that would work for me :)

Comment: @FirstOne It is already serialized and gets serialized again

Comment: To get what you want, you will have to pre-process `$_POST['wmw_age']` into a comma delimited list. ___Although that is a worse idea than serializing it___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$data = join(', ', $_POST['wmw_age']);
```

You do not have to serialize the array, it can be concatenated with the `join` function, which will turn it into a string by joining all values with a given string(glue). ( `', '` in the above example )

The result will be: **0-4 years, 10th group** in case both checkboxes are checked, **10th group** or **0-4 years** in case only one checkbox is checked and an empty string in case none is checked.

> Thanks to @RiggsFolly for pointing out, that the serialized string is serialized again by update_post_meta, so a deserialization is unnecessary.

Comment: ___Although comma delimited lists in a single table column is a worse idea than serializing it___

Comment: And come to think of it `$_POST['wmw_age']` is not what is serialized anyway. Thats just an array!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree, that storing a comma sperated list into a database is a bad idea, if the data shall later be analysed again. For simple output it is ok.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Based on the provided example `$_POST['wmw_age']` is a serialized array.

Comment: No, the array `$_POST['wmw_age']` is serialized into `$data` and `$data` is stored, serialized, onto the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Based on the documentation it is only serialized if an array is provided. [wordpress documentation for update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: Not sure if this is standard WP code or OwnCode. From the code OP shows he always serializes whatever is in `$_POST['wmw_age']`

Comment: Thanks both. Although I don't completely understand the discussion, I'm afraid. However, If I use $data = join(', ', unserialize($_POST['wmw_age'])); instead of the old $data line I had, the result in the database is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jason remove the `unserialize()` part to `$data = join(', ', $_POST['wmw_age']);` to see if it works then. It is what @RiggsFolly' s point is in the discussion above. If it works it should store something like `s:21:"0-4 years, 10th group"` in the database, in whichs case i cannot help you really. :-(

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Yes, this does the trick! Now it's just this in the database: 0-4 years, 10th group. So the whole serializing was a bad idea in this case... :) Thanks!